# Can't get same color of original image when saving same image in OpenCv, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, scipy

I have written a code to rotate images and save them. So I used OpenCv to save rotated image. After save the rotated image, It gets blue on the image.

OS : Ubuntu 16.04

This is the code :

```
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
from scipy.misc import imread, imshow
import cv2
count = 0
while True:
    if count<230:
    filename = 'frame'+str(count)+'.jpg'
    print(filename)
    img = imread(filename)

    rotate_img = rotate(img, 90)
    cv2.imwrite(filename,rotate_img)
    count = count + 1
        continue
    else :
    break
```

Why color change like this? What should I need to do?
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in Advanced!

Image(Before saved) :

[image]

Image(After saved) :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the problem. I have to convert color of image into RGB color.

```
cv2.cvtColor(rotate_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Here is the code :

```
from scipy.ndimage import rotate
from scipy.misc import imread, imshow
import cv2
count = 0
while True:
    if count<230:
    filename = 'frame'+str(count)+'.jpg'
    print(filename)
    img = imread(filename)

    rotate_img = rotate(img, 90)
    #convert color of image before saving
    rgbImg = cv2.cvtColor(rotate_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imwrite(filename,rgbImg)
    count = count + 1
        continue
    else :
    break
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're using scipy's `imread` that creates RGB images and OpenCV `imwrite` that writes images assuming they are BGR.

Invert the first and third channels of your images.

Comment: Thanks sunreef for answer. you are right It was the problem I guess. I used "cv2.cvtColor(rotate_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)" to get color.